# Delete new lines at the end of the string

Tags: php, newline

I have a string from a textarea and I want to delete all new lines after the last word or character?

For example I have this string from the textbox

```
 $str = "Hi, my name is Blah

 x)

 ";
```

I need to remove new lines after the last word or character which is x)

So the results should be like this

```
 $result = "Hi my name is Blah

 x)";
```

I have tried str_replace, explode, rtrim but I cannot think of the algorithm.

Note: I don't want to remove ALL new lines. Just the one after the last word or character. TIA

Comment: Can't get to a computer to test, but `$result = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $str) ` should work.

Comment: *See note. Thanks. What that does is that it removes ALL line breaks.

Comment: Should only remove line breaks at the end, thus the `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)? If you omit the second parameter it will do **exactly** what you want.

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the end
>   of str.
>
> Without the second parameter, rtrim() will strip these characters:
>
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
>   "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
>   "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
>   "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
>   "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NULL-byte.
>   "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

Here is **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2S1ZpC)** demo

Comment: Right. I forgot the nl2br. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. FYI `nl2br` is in the example just to show you that there are no trailing new line characters in the string.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to echo the string without the nl2br before that's why I thought rtrim was not working. Thanks again.